# how to keep OrbitControl camera position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I'm making a 360deg scene with `@react/three-fiber` and `@react/three-drei`, with 2 types of controls: Orbit and Device Orientation.

And I want to keep my current camera position form Device Orientation to Orbit Controls, but it didn't work.

How to OrbitControl (or Device Orientation) control my camera, and how to get current position or any coords of camera to update later?

Comment: add piece of your tried code

Comment: thansk, this is my demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-three-control-wj15p?file=/src/features/world/Scene.js